# Calculating price change & cumulative percentage change in price based on conditions on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Background of the problem is I am trying to backtest a trading strategy and evaluate my portfolio performance over time. I am using Pandas DataFrame to manipulate the data.

I've generated dummy data using

```
data = {'position': [1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
        'close': [10,25,30,25,22,20,21,16,11,20], 
        'close_position' : [10,25,30,25,22,22,22,16,11,20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

output df would be

```
+-------+----------+------------+----------------+
| index | position | close      | close_position |
+-------+----------+------------+----------------+
|     0 |        1 |         10 |             10 |
|     1 |        0 |         25 |             25 |
|     2 |        0 |         30 |             30 |
|     3 |        0 |         25 |             25 |
|     4 |       -1 |         22 |             22 |
|     5 |        0 |         20 |             22 |
|     6 |        0 |         21 |             22 |
|     7 |        1 |         16 |             16 |
|     8 |        0 |         11 |             11 |
|     9 |       -1 |         20 |             20 |
+-------+----------+------------+----------------+
```

Column `position` tells when to take a position. `1` represents buying & `-1` represents selling.

I start by allocating say $100 at index 0 where price is represented by `close` i.e `10` & I sell at index 4 when price is `22` so my portfolio increases by 120% which takes my invested amount to `100 + 120 = 220`. At index `5` & `6` I take no position therefore the change in my portfolio would be 0% and I would be maintaining $220.

At index `7` I buy again but this time instead of using $100 I use $220 to buy at close price `16` and sell at `20` thereby increasing my portfolio by 25%. Now I would have `220 + 55 = 275`.

I've used the code below to generate column `change` which tells the change in price with respect to index 0 & `pct_change` calculates the percentage change from base price. I want to change the base price in line 3 of below code i.e. `df.close.iloc[0]` dynamically based on the column `position`. At index `7` I want to change `df.close.iloc[0]` in line 3 with `df.close.iloc[7]` & I want `alloc` to change to `220` since now I would be investing $220 as I would be taking a new position.

Line 2 of below code also takes difference in close price with respect to index 0, which is fine till index `6` but from index `7` onwards I want to compute difference in price with respect to index 7.

```
alloc = 100 # allocation amount
df['change_cumsum'] = df.close_position.diff().cumsum()
df['pct_change_cumsum'] = alloc + ((df.change_cumsum / df.close.iloc[0]) * alloc)
```

Current Output:

```
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| index | position | close | close_position | change        | pct_change        |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
|     0 |        1 |    10 |             10 | NaN           | NaN               |
|     1 |        0 |    25 |             25 | 15            | 250               |
|     2 |        0 |    30 |             30 | 20            | 300               |
|     3 |        0 |    25 |             25 | 15            | 250               |
|     4 |       -1 |    22 |             22 | 12            | 220               |
|     5 |        0 |    20 |             22 | 12            | 220               |
|     6 |        0 |    21 |             22 | 12            | 220               |
|     7 |        1 |    16 |             16 | 6             | 160               |
|     8 |        0 |    11 |             11 | 1             | 110               |
|     9 |        0 |    20 |             20 | 10            | 200               |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| index | position | close | close_position | change.       | pct_change        |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
|     0 |        1 |    10 |             10 |             0 |                 0 |
|     1 |        0 |    25 |             25 |            15 |               250 |
|     2 |        0 |    30 |             30 |            20 |               300 |
|     3 |        0 |    25 |             25 |            15 |               250 |
|     4 |       -1 |    22 |             22 |            12 |               220 |
|     5 |        0 |    20 |             22 |            12 |               220 |
|     6 |        0 |    21 |             22 |            12 |               220 |
|     7 |        1 |    16 |             16 |             0 |                220|
|     8 |        0 |    11 |             11 |            -5 |            151.25 |
|     9 |        0 |    20 |             20 |             4 |               275 |
+-------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I think I noticed an inconsistency in your desired output: your column `pct_change` is your change in percentage of your alloc position. I'm wondering what you have in mind from index 7: you start a position with 0% change, but at index 8 I would expect to see -31 instead of 151.25. What is actually this column about ?

Comment: If I allocate $220 at index 7, I would be taking a new position and at index 7 percentage change in my portfolio would be 0% so value at index 7 should be 220 (this is my mistake I've made an edit). But if you reduce -31% from $220 so you should get $151.25 at index 8 which is correct.

Comment: Ok makes sense now! If I have a way to find `pct_change` without needing `change`, is it still acceptable for you ?

Comment: Yes that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

First I add a `net_position` column to consider your cumulative position. I shift it by 1 to take into account that the position is only effective the next day (bought when market is closed)

```py
df['net_position'] = df.position.cumsum().shift().fillna(0)
```

Then the way to calculate the value of your investment, is by computing the percentage change between each close. By multiplying this by the cumulative position, you only consider changes when the position is not null. Finally, you add one to this change percentage to obtain a relative change, and perform a cumulative product to get the percentage of change of your investment.

```py
df['change'] = (df.close.pct_change() * df.net_position + 1).cumprod() * alloc

    position    close   close_position  net_position    change
0   1           10      10              0.0 
1   0           25      25              1.0             250
2   0           30      30              1.0             300
3   0           25      25              1.0             250
4   -1          22      22              1.0             220
5   0           20      22              0.0             220
6   0           21      22              0.0             220
7   1           16      16              0.0             220
8   0           11      11              1.0             151.25
9   0           20      20              1.0             275
```

Comment: This solution does not takes into account the allocation amount and only works if initial allocation is $100. I've used allocation as a variable in my question & I expect it to be treated as a variable in the solution.

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong, but just multiplying `df['change_%']` by alloc is what you want. The cumprod assumes that you fully reinvest the money you've gotten with the previous sell. It works no matter how much is the original `alloc` (try with 200 for example). I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes that would do the task by `df['change_%']` multiplying with allocation.

Comment: It was already mentioned at the end of my answer but it's okay, I made the edit to consider `alloc` directly